# How to pass child component state to parent component state in React.js functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass the Child component `state` to parent component `state`, I was done once in a class base component but in the functional component, it doesn't work anymore.

Here is my model below:

[image]

And that is the components

```
const Search = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Search Anything</h1>
            <form>
                <InuptForm />
                <input type="submit">Search</input>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

const InuptForm = () => {
    const [search, setSearch] = React.useState('');

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setSearch(e.target.value);
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Search Anything</h1>
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="search" value={search} onChange={handleChange} />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

> **Or is there any chance to use `useReducer` hook to overcome the issue?**

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you cant pass state upwards in React. it is one-directional. if you want the state in the parent you need to "lift the state up". that means place it in the parent component

do something like this:

```
const Search = ({ handleChange }) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Search Anything</h1>
            <form>

                <input type="submit" onChange={handleChange}>Search</input>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

const InuptForm = () => {
    const [search, setSearch] = React.useState('');

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setSearch(e.target.value);
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <Search handleChange={handleChange} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

I'm rendering `<Search />` inside `<InputForm />` here and then passing down the `handleChange` prop

Comment: Thanks for your valuable info! Can you please advice me, is there any chances to use useReducer hook for fixed the issue like my way? @RedBaron

Comment: I don't think your state is complicated enough to use `useReducer`. `useState` is fine. what do you want to achieve with `useReducer`?

Comment: Actually that is the concept like Child To Parent component pass state. I want to do that by anyhow even `useReducer`

Comment: I have already changed that for you. I'm not sure what else you want. you don't need to use `useReducer` here. `useState` is fine

Answer (score 0):

States cannot be passed to Parent components from child component, instead what you can do is create state in parent component and then pass it as prop to child, so on change function in child will update state in parent component.

```js
const Search = () => {
    const [search, setSearch] = React.useState('');

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setSearch(e.target.value);
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Search Anything</h1>
            <form>
                <InuptForm value={search} handler={handleChange} />
                <input type="submit">Search</input>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

const InuptForm = ({value, handler}) => {

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Search Anything</h1>
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="search" value={value} onChange={(e) => handler(e)} />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```